# Can the pointer in a struct pointer method be reassigned to another instance?

Tags: pointers, methods, go, tree

I've been looking into Golang and have been implementing a few data structures to learn how the language works.  I've come across the following issue while writing the code for an AVL tree:

Assigning the primary pointer from a struct pointer method seems to have no effect outside the scope of the function.  E.g. `tree.rotateLeftToRoot()` doesn't result in `tree.left` becoming the new tree.

**Question:** Is there a way to reassign the pointer in a struct pointer method in Golang, or is this generally discouraged?  In the example this would be the `"tree = prevLeft"` line.

Code snippet:

```
//Graphical representation of t.rotateLeftToRoot():
//      t                  L
//   L     R     ->    LL     t
//LL LR                     LR  R
func (tree *AvlTree) rotateLeftToRoot() {
   if tree == nil {
      return
   }
   prevLeft := tree.left
   if prevLeft != nil {
      tree.left = prevLeft.right //tree.left passed root its right branch
      prevLeft.right = tree      //tree becomes tree.left's right branch
      tree.updateHeight()
      prevLeft.updateHeight()
      tree = prevLeft            //desired behaviour: tree.left becomes the new tree
                                 //actual behaviour: no effect when function returns
   }
}
```

I've tried other combinations of setting the value or address of tree, and none of them had the intended effect. For example, `*tree = *prevLeft` results in an infinite loop.

Additional note: Returning `tree` and setting `"tree = tree.rotateLeftToRoot()"` avoids the issue.  This works, but it seems dirty to be mixing effects and requiring assignment to returned values, when the caller really just wants to be able to call a function to update the tree.

Can the `tree` be set to `prevLeft` from within the function?

Comment: If you want to modify a `tree *` held by someone else you need to write a function that takes (or receives) a `tree **`. In order to modify a pointer you need a pointer to it.

Comment: I'd make it return the updated `*AvlTree`. Alternatively, you could change around your type definitions so what you now call `AvlTree` is named, say, `Node` (or `node` if you don't want it public) and define `type AvlTree *Node`, so a method on `*AvlTree` can change the node pointer. (This would execute just like what @hobbs is talking about, just with different names.) Using a pointer-to-pointer could result in a few more allocations and a little more pointer chasing, but maybe not enough to care about.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried passing a tree** into a function, and it seems to have exactly the same problem. Is there a step I'm missing? `func rotateLeftToRoot(ptrToTreePtr **AvlTree) { ... tree := *ptrToTreePtr /*manipulations on tree, tree = prevLeft*/ *ptrToTreePtr = tree }`

Once the function returns, the tree points to the original node instead of to prevLeft.

Comment: I tried again with updated tests, and the local function rotateLeft(ptree **AvlTree) worked successfully.  Thank you hobbs and twotwotwo for your suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pointers are values just like let's say `int` numbers. The difference is the interpretation of that value: pointers are interpreted as memory addresses, and `int`s are interpreted as integer numbers.

When you want to change the value of a variable of type `int`, you pass a pointer to that `int` which is of type `*int`, and you modify the pointed object: `*i = newvalue` (the value assigned is an `int`).

Same goes with pointers: when you want to change the value of a variable of pointer type `*int`, you pass a pointer to that `*int` which is of type `**int` and you modify the pointed object: `*i = &newvalue` (the value assigned is an `*int`).

<sup>Passing a pointer is required because a copy is made from everything you pass, and you could only modify the copy. When you pass a pointer, the same thing happens: a copy is also made of that pointer, but we're not modifying the pointer itself but the *pointed* value.</sup>

You want to modify a variable of type `*AvlTree`. In Go the receiver cannot be a pointer to pointer. [Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> The receiver's type must be of the form `T` or `*T`(possibly using parentheses) where `T` is a type name.  The type denoted by `T` is called the receiver *base type*; **it must not be a pointer** or interface type and it must be declared in the same package as the method.

So you have 2 choices:

1. either write a simple function (not method) that takes a `**AvlTree` and you can pass the address of your tree pointer, so the function can modify the tree pointer (the pointed object)
2. or return the tree pointer from your function/method and have the caller assign it to the variable being the tree pointer.

Addressing your concerns regarding returning the tree pointer: there's nothing wrong with that. Take a look at the builtin function [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append): it appends elements to a slice *and* returns the modified slice. You (the caller) have to assign the returned slice to your slice variable, because `append()` may modify the slice by allocating a new one if the additional elements do not fit into the original (and since `append()` takes a non-pointer, the modified value must be returned).

Here's how the solution going with #1 would look like:

```
func rotateLeftToRoot(ptree **AvlTree) {
    tree := *ptree
    if tree == nil {
        return
    }
    prevLeft := tree.left
    if prevLeft != nil {
        tree.left = prevLeft.right
        prevLeft.right = tree
        tree = prevLeft
    }
    *ptree = tree
}
```

I've implemented it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uOS1s4xF65) to prove it works.

I've used this type:

```
type AvlTree struct {
    value string
    left  *AvlTree
    right *AvlTree
}
```

And to easily check the result, I've implemented some methods to produce a `string` representation:

```
func (tree *AvlTree) String() string { return tree.str(1) }

func (tree *AvlTree) str(n int) string {
    if tree == nil {
        return "<nil>"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%q\n%s%v,%v\n%s", tree.value, strings.Repeat("\t", n),
        tree.left.str(n+1), tree.right.str(n+1), strings.Repeat("\t", n-1))
}
```

And this is how a tree is constructed and transformed:

```
tree := &AvlTree{
    value: "t",
    left: &AvlTree{
        value: "L",
        left: &AvlTree{
            value: "LL",
        },
        right: &AvlTree{
            value: "LR",
        },
    },
    right: &AvlTree{
        value: "R",
    },
}
fmt.Println(tree)
rotateLeftToRoot(&tree)
fmt.Println(tree)
```

The original tree (without transformation):

```
"t"
    "L"
        "LL"
            <nil>,<nil>
        ,"LR"
            <nil>,<nil>

    ,"R"
        <nil>,<nil>
```

And the transformed tree (exactly what you wanted):

```
"L"
    "LL"
        <nil>,<nil>
    ,"t"
        "LR"
            <nil>,<nil>
        ,"R"
            <nil>,<nil>
```

Comment: Thank you icza for the thorough answer.  I had a working version that returns the new pointer, and was looking for a way to update the pointer value from within a function or struct method, as described in your option 1.  I tried this again with rewritten tests and it works as intended.

Most of the information is already understood or contained in other people's comments, but this is a very well-formed post that may be useful to other people as well.

Comment: Is there a Golang preference between keeping a struct method that returns a new value, and having a local function that updates the struct pointer value?

Comment: @Saigo Whichever suits you. Passing a `**AvlTree` is safer as the caller don't have to remember to assign the return value, but the other solution is easier to understand, and it can be a method (not just a function). I would go with the `**AvlTree` for safety, but that's just my personal preference.