# Updating value in pointer reciever method but value not updating

Tags: pointers, go, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list in Go. I wrote a method to insert a node at the beginning of the linked list:

```
func (n *node) insertAtBegining(d int){
    nn := &node{d,n}
    n = nn
}
```

The method being a pointer receiver should update the node `n`, but it fails to do so.

For example,

```
head.printList()
head.insertAtBegining(30)
head.printList()
```

returns

```
42 -> 56 -> 89 -> nil
42 -> 56 -> 89 -> nil
```

You can see the full implementation at https://play.golang.org/p/rpI6lbAywOQ.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See possible duplicate: [Can the pointer in a struct pointer method be reassigned to another instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421495/can-the-pointer-in-a-struct-pointer-method-be-reassigned-to-another-instance/35426997?r=SearchResults#35426997)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Xw3wCGRBNEl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the issue is that calling `head.insertAtBegining(30)` does not change the value of head (it still points at the `node{42, nil}`).

You have developed this on the asumption that the `n = nn` in `insertAtBegining` will update `head` but that is not the case. I think it's easier to understand if `insertAtBegining` is a standard function rather than a [method](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

```
insertAtBegining(head, 30)
...
func insertAtBegining(n *node, d int) *node{
    nn := &node{d,n}
    n = nn
}
```

As Go passes all parameters by value (you can pass a pointer but that is passed as a value) I think it's clear that this would not change `head` (if you wanted to do that you would need to define the function `func insertAtBegining(n **node, d int) *node{` and pass it `&head`.

The issue is the same in your method.

The simplest fix for this is to redefine `insertAtBegining` as ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dJ4fKrEnB8s)):

```
func (n *node) insertAtBegining(d int) *node{
    nn := &node{d,n}
    return nn
}
```

It now returns the new head so you use it like: `head = head.insertAtBegining(30)`.

Another approach is to encapuslate the list management within a struct; this is the approach taken in [list.List](https://golang.org/src/container/list/list.go?s=1309:1486#L38). Doing this has the advantage that the user needs no understanding of how the list is stored.